# Error al importar from app import mongo en Python con Flask & Flask restful

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

Estoy construyendo una api en python con flask & flask restful

La aplicación está desplegada con docker compose y tiene el siguiente scafolding.

- api/

  - app.py
  - models/

    - data.py
- docker-compose.yml

** Al ejecutarse el docker compose se crea el build de una imagen en python dentro de la carpeta api. (Con los archivos de la api en flask)

Soy un poco nuevo en Flask y python. Estoy intentando hacer una api que se asemeje al modelo MVC; separada en modelos - controladores.

La api está conectada con una base de datos en Mongo a través de flask_pymongo.

En el archivo app.py tengo lo que serian los Resources, con algunos métodos(Luego lo separare en controladores) para ir testeando. Pero al iniciar la api me sale un error de importación del archivo de modelos y crashea la api. Adjunto el error y la estructura de archivosde la api.

ESTRUCTURA ARCHIVOS:

**app.py**

```
import os
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo
#y los demas import.. ...

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
mongo = PyMongo(app, uri="") #Aqui tengo la url de la bbdd


from models.data import Test
class test(Resource):
   def post(self):
        response = Test.post()
        return response
        #Esto es un ejemplo de la llamada que hago

api.add_resource(test, '/test')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

**models/data.py**

```
from app import mongo
class Test():

    @classmethod
    def post(self):
        mongo.db.test.insert_one({
            #Aqui la logica etc..
        })
        return True
```

ERROR DE LA CONSOLA AL INICIAR LA APP:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'Test' from partially initialized
>   module 'models.data' (most likely due to a circular import)
>   (E:\source\develop\api\service\models\data.py)

PD: Los nombres de los archivos todos están bien,

He esto investigando en el código y el fallo está en el archivo de modelos. No está importando bien el

```
from app import mongo
```

Por este motivo, cuando inicia app.py como hay un error en el archivo de los modelos no lo importa bien. (Lo importa parcialmente)

Si comento esta linea y lee paso la variable `mongo` desde la llamada en el archivo app.py, si funciona. 
Realiza las operaciones bbdd correctamente etc..
(Esto validad el error)

Alguien me podría ayudar para ver como importar bien esto. He buscado información pero no consigo dar con la solución

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que tienes un import circular, `data.py` importa de `app.py` y luego `app.py` intenta importar `data.py`. Esto por norma general es un error de diseño.

La secuencia es:

1. Ejecutas `app.py`

   2. Se define la variable global `mongo` en  `mongo = PyMongo(app, uri="")`.
   3. Se importa data.py: `from models.data import Test`.

      4. Se importa app.py en `from app import mongo`.

¿Problema? En el punto 4 `app.py` no ha sido inicializado al completo cuando se intenta importar, se ha quedado en la línea `from app import mongo`.

Una solución muy simple es importar dentro del método dado que este código no es evaluado cuando el módulo se importa:

```
class Test():
    @classmethod
    def post(self):
        from app import mongo
        mongo.db.test.insert_one({
            #Aqui la logica etc..
        })
        return True
```

Pero dado que obtener una referencia a la BD es una operación común, es recomendable crear un módulo aparte para éstas operaciones, así simplificas y eliminas los imports circulares de paso. Algo así:

**`/api/app.py`**

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

from db import get_db
from models.data import Test


app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
mongo = get_db()


class Test_(Resource):
    def post(self):
        response = Test.post()
        return response
        # Esto es un ejemplo de la llamada que hago


api.add_resource(Test_, '/test')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

**`/api/db.py`**

```
from flask import current_app, g
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo


MONGO_URI = ""


def get_db():
    if 'db' not in g:
        g.db = PyMongo(current_app, usi=MONGO_URI)
    return g.db
```

**`/api/models/data.py`**

```
from db import get_db


class Test():
    @classmethod
    def post(cls):
        mongo = get_db()
        mongo.db.test.insert_one({
            ###
        })
        return True
```

Comment: Muchas gracias ha funcionado perfecto!